# Magento2 How to show wholesale price for product, if customer is logged in as wholesale customer group?

Tags: magento2, product, price, customer-group

I have the setup of Magento2 Store. We are using tier pricing for customer groups. So if the customer is associated with the (wholesale group) and logged in, the customer must see the only wholesale price on the product listing page & product details page.

We have the same wholesale price for all sizes, so we need to just pull in the wholesale price for that product.

Please find the screenshot for your reference.
[image]

Thanks

Comment: Did you check on frontend after login as wholesale customer?

Comment: Yes, i did. Please find attached screenshot for your reference.  Backend Screen- https://prnt.sc/jd3wc1 & FrontEnd Screen - https://prnt.sc/jd3x10

Comment: @AjayJaiswal,did you got any solution?

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need to manage the product form **cost** field.

***If you will set at  Price and manage wholesale group price from "Customer group price" field then you easily manage your requirement.***

But note that Price field should be greater "Customer group price"'s wholesales group.

Comment: Hi Amit, Thank you for responding to my issue. I did the same thing but it didn't work. Still, retail price is showing when i logged in as wholesale customer group. Please find attached screenshot for your reference.  Backend Screen- https://prnt.sc/jd3wc1 & FrontEnd Screen - https://prnt.sc/jd3x10

Comment: Hi Amit, just for information - I am using the configurable product.